# Why do I get notification of receiving these privileges when I have not met the required reputation?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering why I received notification of these privileges on Stackoverflow

[screenshot of the privileges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rSiU.png)

- talk in chat which requires 20 reputation
- documentation votes which requires 15 reputation
- vote up which requires 15 reputation
- flag posts which requires 15 reputation

I only have 9 reputation I should not have received these privileges. However, when I clicked on my profile I see I am still
[working on toward these privileges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpG9a.png)

I am confused. Is this a mistake or a glitch?

**EDIT**
I have never reached beyond 13 reputation before. So it cannot be the case of me loose reputation after received these prvileges.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am aware I got downvoted yesterday from 11 to 9 but I am sure my reputation never went above 13.

Comment: Someone probably upvoted one of your posts then retracted the vote again. Votes undone on the same day are not listed in your reputation record, but such a sequence of events would give you exactly that privilege message.